# Internal compiler error: Illegal instruction in gcc while trying to compile sqlite3.c

Tags: gcc, sqlite

I am insisting to compile OMNet ++ and at the time of compiling sqlite3.c it shows me the following error:

```
sqlite3.c: In function ‘computeJD’:
sqlite3.c:18784:3: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction
   p->iJD = (sqlite3_int64)((X1 + X2 + D + B - 1524.5 ) * 86400000);
   ^
```

The source code of sqlite3.c on that line shows:

```
  X1 = 36525*(Y+4716)/100;
  X2 = 306001*(M+1)/10000;
  p->iJD = (sqlite3_int64)((X1 + X2 + D + B - 1524.5 ) * 86400000);
  p->validJD = 1;
```

I do not see where the error can be. Will it be that I need to pass some flag to the compiler ???

Answer (score 0):

Your GCC compiler binary apparently has been compiled for the wrong subarchitecture, so that floating point computations cause `SIGILL` traps.  On x86, this could happen if you run a compiler compiled for an AVX2-capable CPU on a non-AVX2 machine, for example.

Comment: The GCC compiler has been compiled just before trying to compile OMNet ++. I am using EasyBuild for this task, exactly foss-2016b. I understand that EasyBuild compiles the toolchain first before compiling the software in question. That is, GCC compiles exactly in the same environment.

Comment: Is the machine you use to run the compiler exactly the same machine on which you build it? By default, Easybuild requires this.